# Duplicate class org.webrtc.AddIceObserver found in modules jetified-libwebrtc

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webrtc, voximplant

I was using voximplant for P2P video call, and I wanted integrate live broadcast/streaming call just like Teams or Jitsu using react-native-webrtc. How can I resovle this issue? Thank you advance for your help.

> But as I installed react-native-webrtc,I seeing duplicate eorros like
> rhe following below Execution failed for task
> ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> > Duplicate class org.webrtc.AddIceObserver found in modules jetified-libwebrtc (libwebrtc.jar) and
> > jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime
> > (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0) etc.